# Why won't importlib find my module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, python-import

I'm trying to programmatically import a module.

This works:

```
from dirname.models import modelclass as m
```

But this doesn't:

```
import importlib
m = importlib.import_module('models.modelclass', package='dirname')
```

I try running this script from the directory that holds dirname. dirname contains a `__init__.py` file.

I'm trying to make this work using django. I get an ImportError saying "No module named 'models'"

Comment: you meant "dirname contains an `__init__.py` file, right?

Comment: @progmatico Yup. I just failed to put it within code tags, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was confusion over what I was trying to do, in the question modelclass is a method, models is the module, and dirname is the package. import_module imports modules, not methods (as the name suggests). To programmatically import the method modelclass I can use getattr():

```
import dirname.models as mods 
# or "mods = importlib.import_module('dirname.models')"
m = getattr(mods, 'modelclass')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need to specify the package kwarg, import_module says this about the package kwarg:

> The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
>       specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
>       relative import to an absolute import.

I usually just use importlib.import_module in this way (I guess specifying it as an absolute import):

```
import importlib
m = importlib.import_module('package.models.ModelClass')
```

Sometimes I might set a variable in django settings like `MY_CLASS='package.models.ModelClass'` and use import_module to switch between what class is being used.

Comment: If I do that then I get "No moduel named 'dirname.models.modelclass'; 'data_feed.models' is not a package". It's true,as I understand it, dirname is the package, models is the module and modelclass is the item I want to import. I'm going to give your MY_CLASS method a go...

Comment: I think I've figured it out, the problem is that I'm trying to import a function not a module, so import_module isn't what I want. I need to import the module models as normal, and then access ModelClass using getattr(). Thanks for the assistance, it set me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Well I'm glad you got to the bottom of it, dynamic imports can be really powerful.  Enjoy!